# How to create abstract class, and extend it using Doctrine2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to create an abstract class, called `Content`. There are two implementations: `TextContent` and `VideoContent`

```
abstract class Content {

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    private $title;

    /** getters and setters... **/

}
```

And the implementations:

```
class VideoContent extends Content {

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    private $source;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    private $format;

    /** getters and setters... **/


}
```

---

```
class TextContent extends Content {

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    private $text_data;

    /** getters and setters... **/


}
```

The Content has to be abstract, bacause a content can't be just content. It's Video or Text. How is it possible in Doctrine2? And how will this be represented in the MySQL database?

Comment: No, because I don't know, how should I create the tables in the database. Do I have to create 3 tables, or just 2? And with which columns? (I cant generate the tables using Doctrine, bacause I have no command line access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

You will have to create a single table with a discriminator column.